# preg_match on special characters

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I’m trying to make a `preg_match` in my PHP code, but I can't seem to get it to work.

I have these 3 tags

```
{$success url='http://www.domain.localhost/form-success'}
{$error url='http://www.domain.localhost/form-error'}
{$button title='send form'}
```

How can I get my `preg_match` to accept what I’m trying to do?

I’m trying to get `{$button(*)}` out to my match path, and the same I want to do with the 2 others `{$success(*)}` and `{$error(*)}`

Now I think it should look like this

```
preg_match("/\{\$button(.+?)}/s", $content, $match);
```

But it still isn’t working, so I hope other people can help me here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\$` already means "literal $" in PHP strings, so when put in a regex it just means "end of string".

Try `\\\$` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the closing `}` and need to use `preg_match_all` to match all the lines.

Try this regex:

```
preg_match('/\{\$(?:success|error|button)\s+([^}]+)\}/i', $content, $match );
```

#### Working Demo: http://ideone.com/fKq5L2

#### OUTPUT:

```
Array
(
    [0] => {$success url='http://www.domain.localhost/form-success'}
    [1] => {$error url='http://www.domain.localhost/form-error'}
    [2] => {$button title='send form'}
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i need it to seperate eg. button content like {$button title='send form'} when you run your reg.exp. its need to return like this [0] => {$button title='send form'}, [1] => title='send form'

Comment: btw if you use `print_r($match);` you will find your expected content in `$match[1]`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the correct regex to retrieve the 'button' tag should be : `\{\$button([^\}]*)\}`

You can try your expression on http://regexpal.com/

So with php :

```
preg_match("/\{\$button([^\}]*)\}/s", $content, $match );
```